# Динамическое построение PDF-документов

Tags: php, java, android, fpdf

Есть андроид приложение, в которое посылает скрипту сайта запрос на формирование PDF документа. Выглядит это так: [image: Скрин формирования документа]

Планируется следующая логика:

1. Вместе с запросом в скрипт отправляется переменная **case** и данные
2. В зависимости от **case** формируется документ pdf в скрипте php.
3. Документ отображается в приложении и доступен для скачивания через кнопку приложения.

При отправке переменной **case** в скрипт, документ не формируется внутри события, которое отвечает за проверку прихода в скрипт **case**. Вот это место: [image: Здесь должен формироваться документ php при условии, что переменная пришла]

Здесь должен формироваться документ php при условии, что переменная пришла, но этого не происходит. 
Подскажите в чём ошибся и как заставить документ формироваться динамически?

С серверной части для формирования документа пользуюсь [этим](http://www.fpdf.org/)
На андроиде ловлю и вывожу документ с помощью этой [библиотеки](https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager)

Скриншот итоговой реализации, планируется динамическая перерисовка графика исходя из запрошенных данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Приложение пишет ошибку: java.io.IOException: file not in PDF format or corrupted.

Comment: у вас в приложении есть кнопка Ссылка, которая очевидно представляет собой get-запрос. а на стороне пхп вы обрабатываете POST-запрос. Тут нет никакой путаницы?

Comment: Кнопка ссылка больше для украшения. Она копирует ссылку адреса скрипта с сайта в буфер обмена

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно дать конкретного ответа, потому что нет технической составляющей - что вы отправляете и как вы отправляете GET POST, нет кода из андроид приложения. почему 100% уверенность что `case` это число? Меньше скриншотов, больше сути проблемы.

Comment: просто сохраните полученный файл и посмотрите что получили

Comment: Сохранить документ возможно только в том же потоке, в котором он и был создан, иначе он теряется. Не могу понять как именно в коде я должен его сохранять, чтобы поток не закрылся